# Error al levantar pagina localmente

Tags: angular

estoy trabajando con una pagina creada con angular 2, y al descargar el código y tratar de levantarla localmente me aparece el siguiente error. Alguna sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, pegá el código del componente account-plan.ts :p

Answer (score 0):

Los errores de referencia suelen ser básicos en cuanto a que refieren, como en este caso, a que estás haciendo referencia (en la línea 132 de account-plan.ts) a una variable que no fue declarada.

Sin haber visto tu código, imagino que lo más probable es que si declarás la variable al inicio de la clase, el error desaparece:

```
public accounting_1: any;
```